# fitBounds(LatLngBounds) zooming fully out

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm setting a map to fitBounds using this line

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(fromLoc, theLoc);
console.log(bound);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[image]

As you can see when that line runs the map fully zooms out despite the 2 LatLng's only being around 20 minutes drive away.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(fromLoc, theLoc);
```

You are creating a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) with the southWest corner at fromLoc and the northEast corner at theLoc.

To make a bounds that contains those two locations, do this instead:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); // empty bounds
bounds.extend(fromLoc);
bounds.extend(theLoc);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```